# How to select numerical values that start with certain numbers? R Programming

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column in my dataframe that identifies the state. I am doing this based on a postal code map and a postal code column. For example, Texas starts with 75 - 79 so all zip codes that start with 75 will have their state column as Texas.

Answer (score 1):

You may like the zipcodeR package

```
library(zipcodeR)
reverse_zipcode(14853)$state
1 row of data found for ZIP code: '14853' 
[1] "NY"
```